# how to pass datepicker and text together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to send information via ajax.For this i have an input field where I need to enter text along with some date.To enter date,I used datepicker.The problem I am facing is that only date is passed.For example if i write `12/12/2013 12:12 this is a text` then only `12/12/2013 12:12` passed.May I know how to solve this?

```
<script> 
$('#tabAll').click(function(){ 
$('#tabAll').addClass('active'); 
$('.tab-pane').each(function(i,t){ 
$('#myTabs li').removeClass('active'); 
$(this).addClass('active'); 
}); 
}); 
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(){ 
if(this.id=='openAlert')
    {$('#number').val('');}else{$('#number').val(this.id);}
});
</script> 
<script >



        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#openAlert').click(function(){

            var number = $('#number').val(); // If its a text input could use .text()
            var msg = $('#body').val(); //If its a text input could use .text()
alert(number);
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "messageSending.jsp", //Your full URL goes here
                    data: { toNumber: number, body: msg},
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        alert(data);                  
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR){
                        alert(jqXHR.responseStatus);
                    }
                });
        });
    });
        </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
        language: 'eng'
      });
    </script>
```

**html**

```
<div class="span3">    <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
                            <input type="text" name="body" maxlength="160" placeholder="Enter message to send" id="body" data-trigger="hover">
                            </input><span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: What scripting language are you using? PHP?

Comment: @JoelMurphy I am using jsp as server side

Comment: @JoelMurphy Please tell me if the jquery code is right or wrong

Comment: alert msg after number and see whether ur obtaining the value there..

Comment: @Shashank sorry i did not understand

Comment: insert alert(msg); after alert(number); in your code
and see what does the browser show!!

Comment: @Shashank no I am not getting msg,alert shows only date

Comment: @Shashank I am getting only date and time

Answer (score 0):

DateTimePicker Input did not return text as value it always return date-format only you can use another input field to get the text

Answer (score 0):

Can u copy this script and tell me what the second alert shows..
i mean the after the date alert...

```
   <script> 
    $('#tabAll').click(function(){ 
    $('#tabAll').addClass('active'); 
    $('.tab-pane').each(function(i,t){ 
    $('#myTabs li').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
    }); 
    }); 
    $('body').on('click', '.btn', function(){ 
    if(this.id=='openAlert')
        {$('#number').val('');}else{$('#number').val(this.id);}
    });
    </script> 
    <script >



            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#openAlert').click(function(){

                var number = $('#number').val(); // If its a text input could use .text()
                var msg = $('#body').val(); //If its a text input could use .text()
    alert(number);
    alert(msg);
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "messageSending.jsp", //Your full URL goes here
                        data: { toNumber: number, body: msg},
                        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                            alert(data);                  
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR){
                            alert(jqXHR.responseStatus);
                        }
                    });
            });
        });
            </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
          $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
            language: 'eng'
          });
        </script>
```

Comment: I am getting only date and time